# Pool analysis or meta analysis for one arm studies

Tags: pooling

I am new to pooled analysis. Currently I received results of several observational studies. Each study is a clinical trial on patients who have the same disease of interest. In each study, all patients received the same treatment and had the Success rate (the outcome is just success or fail). There are 3 different treatments in all the studies.

My objectives are:

1. Pool the studies together to learn the effectiveness of the treatments.
2. Make comparisons between treatments.

My questions are:

1. How do I measure the effectiveness of each treatment? Maybe calculate the proportion of success and the pooled variance of studies with same treatment? Any other possible measurements?
2. If I know mean age, percent of male/female, .etc of each study, can I adjust for these covariates and get better measurement of effectiveness?
3. Is it possible to make comparisons between treatments? How should I do?
4. Does the data fit the framework of meta analysis? I really like the forest plot but I've read some posts and papers and it looks like the studies included should be two-armed study (treatment&control or treatment A & treatment B).

Comment: Combining information from similar studies to try to draw stronger inference is what meta-analysis is all about.